# Adjusting TabItem width automatically to fill spaces?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, alignment, tabitem

I have a TabControl object with some TabItem objects inside. Now the sum of width of TabItem is not long enough to fill the space on right:

Now I wish to have one of following design:

[alt text http://img111.imageshack.us/img111/4158/67279984.png](http://img111.imageshack.us/img111/4158/67279984.png)

What properties should I set to archieve one of the design above? For the second design, I tried to adjust HorizontalAlignment property (to "center") in TabItem objects and HorizontalContentAglinment property (to "center") in TabControl object, but neither works.

Could someone point out what should I do to implement the design? I prefer the first design, but if it is impossible or very difficult, the second one would be nice too.

Thanks.

Comment: Image link is broken, can you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The tabs are arranged by the TabControl's HeaderPanel. You need to replace the HeaderPanel to change the layout. It seems like the only way to do this is with a ControlTemplate. Here is an article that will show you how to do that: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfSqueezeTabPanel.aspx.

Comment: Close, but I wouldn't use that squeeze panel. Just re-template and use some simpler primitive panel, for example, UniformGrid with Rows set to 1. UniformGrid is intelligent enough to spread out N items equally across the width.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer on this similar question(If I understood correctly):
[How to Stretch WPF Tab Item Headers to Parent Control Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705815/how-to-stretch-wpf-tab-item-headers-to-parent-control-width/17696499#17696499)