# Silverlight stretching TabItem Headers to parent control width

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol

I am creating a SL App that has a TabControl with dynamically created TabItems which are added via code behind. I'd like said TabItems to size proportionally to the TabControls full width, much like what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705815/how-to-stretch-wpf-tab-item-headers-to-parent-control-width).

Now Silverlight does not have IMultiValueConverter, and not knowing how many tab I will have, I am a bit stuck. Any ways around this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself, but I believe you could just implement your own `TabPanel` and substitute that in via the appropriate template part. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol%28VS.95%29.aspx) for a list of template parts.

```
public class MyTabPanel : TabPanel
{
    // custom layout logic as per your requirements
}
```

And in styles:

```
<Style TargetType="TabControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                <!-- copy standard template from Blend, but substitute in your MyTabPanel instead -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```