# Strech TabItem header in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, tabcontrol

How can I cause the tab item headers to stretch across the width of the tab control in Silverlight? If it matters, I have always a fix number of tabs.

I've found just WPF examples, with IMultiValueConverter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705815/how-to-stretch-wpf-tab-item-headers-to-parent-control-width).

Comment: Coding style means the style in which code is writen. It does nor affect the style of the UI. Please see [this clarification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example

http://cid-a1de71e9f2ae2f82.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/ExtendedTabControl.zip

It's preaty simple task.. all you have to do is to create Copy of default template and replace `System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:TabPanel x:Name="TabPanelTop"` with `te:StockPanel x:Name="TabPanelTop"` which basicly override layout logic..

```
public class StockPanel: System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TabPanel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var cc = Children.Count;

        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(new Size(availableSize.Width / cc, availableSize.Height));
        }

        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var cc = Children.Count;
        var i = 0;

        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect((finalSize.Width / cc) * i, 0, finalSize.Width / cc, finalSize.Height));
            i++;
        }

        return new Size(finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height);
    }
}
```

---

**PS: it's not perfect code sample, but i think it's enouth for you to understand how to extend TabControl**

Comment: Thanks, but I can't download your code. Please send me in email!

Comment: try this one http://cid-a1de71e9f2ae2f82.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/ExtendedTabControl.zip