# How do I fill the TabPanel of a TabControl with the TabItem Headers stretching from left to right without leaving free space?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Somehow this does not work:

```
      <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabPanel">
             <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
      </TabControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/804378/302677) work for you?

Comment: @Rachel tx very much, it worked fine! In the converter I just had to subtract 1.4 instead of 1 from the calculated tabitem width to avoid overflow to more rows in the tabpanel.