# WPF Flexible TabControl Header

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I want to have a `TabControl` with multiple `TabItems`. These `TabItems` each have a header text. These texts may vary a lot in length (like 5 chars long and 15 chars long).

I want the `TabControl` to align the headers in one row only.

All tab headers should use the same width, and when there is enough space available, i want them the to use all the space available, up to a `MaxWidth`, that is the same for all items.

So if i want to use vMaxWidth` of 100 for 7 items, the tab header should be max 700 in width. If there is more space available, it should be ignored.

If there is less space available, i want that space to be distributed equally between the items. If the text gets cut off, i want to use `TextWrapping`.

I have tried multiple approaches to this problem now, this is my current setup:

```
<Style x:Key="Style-TabControl-Main" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="13,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Brush-White}">
                        <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="1" x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Background="Transparent" 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </Border>

                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the `TabItem` `Style`

```
<Style x:Key="Style-TabItem-Main" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="31"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="180" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Brush-BrightRegular-Foreground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Cursor="Hand" 
                        Margin="2,0,0,0"
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"
                        CornerRadius="4,4,0,0"
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Brush-BrightRegular-Background}"
                        Background="{DynamicResource Brush-White}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                        TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontSize="16" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"   Value="True">
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Brush-White}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"  Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Brush-DefaultDark-Background}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am using a `StackPanel` instead of a `TabPanel` to get rid of the "stacking", that occurs, when you resize a default `TabControl`. However, i cannot get the rest of my requirements to work. I tried applying a `MaxWidth` (instead of fixed width) to the `TabItem` headers, but that of course doesn't work, because the item than shrinks to its minimum required size.

Comment: I have worked on TabControl some time ago so I can't guarantee that this will work but, firstly you don't need `<Style x:Key="Style-TabItem-Main" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">` a simple `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">` will do, secondly remove the `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` from your `ContentControl`, from I have noticed this will mess up the logic for stretching the content. BTW try to wrap the ContentPresenter in DockPanel. HTH

Comment: I actually need to key, because i am using multiple different TabControl and TabItem styles. This is just one of them!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Step 1 (first attempt):** Put headers in a single row, and give each header the same width.

This can be achieved by using a `UniformGrid` instead of the standard TabPanel, and lock its row count to 1. Here is a stripped-down version of your `TabControl` style:

```
<Style x:Key="Style-TabControl-Main" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Border>
                        <UniformGrid x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="True" 
                                     Rows="1" />
                    </Border>

                    <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.Row="1" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Step 2:** Restrict headers to a `MaxWidth` and apply text wrapping.

The `MaxWidth` can be set in the `TabItem` style, along with a `HeaderTemplate` which wraps text (you can still use your custom `ControlTemplate` here to style the TabItem parts):

```
<Style x:Key="Style-TabItem-Main" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="100" />
    <!--https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/df4f7fc3-f0ec-4ed1-a022-a32650e49cb3/how-to-wrap-header-text-in-tabcontrol-->
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        ...
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Troubleshooting:** Now, if you apply the `MaxWidth` in *Step 2*, you'll probably want to left-align the `UniformGrid` when the TabControl gets too wide..

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="HeaderPanel" IsItemsHost="True" 
             Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

..but you don't want that when the MaxWidth hasn't been reached yet, and the items should stretch across the entire width of the TabControl (aka *Step 1*). So we need a way to switch that `HorizontalAlignment` depending on whether the items' MaxWidth (if set) has been reached.

**Step 1 (revisited)**: Let's try to make our own UniformGrid:

```cs
public class UniformTabPanel : UniformGrid
{
    public UniformTabPanel()
    {
        this.IsItemsHost = true;
        this.Rows = 1;

        //Default, so not really needed..
        this.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var totalMaxWidth = this.Children.OfType<TabItem>().Sum(tab => tab.MaxWidth);
        if (!double.IsInfinity(totalMaxWidth))
        {
            this.HorizontalAlignment = (constraint.Width > totalMaxWidth) 
                                                ? HorizontalAlignment.Left 
                                                : HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        }

        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }
}
```

Now, we can replace the `UniformGrid` in our `TabControl` style this new panel:

```
                ...
                    <Border>
                        <mycontrols:UniformTabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" />
                    </Border>
                ...
```

...and the TabControl should function as expeced.

Comment: I tried your code and it is almost there. However, if i resize the tabcontrol, so that it is larger than the sum of all maxwidths, the tab item headers will take only on the smallest available size available. It still looks very weird.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinxx answer is correct, however i needed to add the following code to the UniformTabPanel, to make it work like i want (resize the headers to maxwidth when enough space is available)

I added the following code to the UniformTabPanel, and it now does what i  need:

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
{
    var children = this.Children.OfType<TabItem>();
    var totalMaxWidth = children.Sum(tab => tab.MaxWidth);
    if (!double.IsInfinity(totalMaxWidth))
    {
        this.HorizontalAlignment = (constraint.Width > totalMaxWidth)
                                            ? HorizontalAlignment.Left
                                            : HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            child.Width = this.HorizontalAlignment == System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
                    ? child.MaxWidth
                    : Double.NaN;
        }
    }
    return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
}
```

Comment: Glad you solved it :) If you don't want to change every TabItem's width, another option might be to set `this.MinWidth = totalMaxWidth` in that case.